# sqrt of a number can't pass online judge

Tags: c++

I am implementing a solution to the problem of sqrt of a number without using the function sqrt. I tried to optimize k for a loop as you can see in the code. The code fails 8th test case, and I have no idea what might that be. If you can help please.

Input:

Contains positive integer numbers n (1 ≤ n≤10^9)

Output:

If n is power of two then write "Yes" and "No" in other cases.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
    int n, k; cin >> n;
    if (n == 1) { cout << "Yes"; return 0; }
    for (k = 2; k <= (n/k)+1; k++) {
        if (n*1.0 / k == k) {
            cout << "Yes";
            return 0;
        }
    }
    cout << "No";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You would need to tell us at least which inputs it is failing on.

Comment: @BoBTFish the online judge doesn't tell which one the code is failing.

Comment: @BoBTFish I tried inputs, corner cases, worst cases, it works.

Comment: @Bathsheba I know the Newton-Raphson one, but the time constrain is 1s, and my optimized brute force one does it nicely within such limits, plus the output is expected to be integer, so no need for newton ramphson.

Comment: @V_head Oops misread the question, better method below (sorry, can't resist).

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but I don't see how this code works for n=9. In loop with k=3 if condition will be true. Even for n=10 it will be true because of integer division. It would be better to use bitwise operations as Bathsheba suggested.

Comment: note that power of two would be `n == 2^x` for some `x` but your code looks more like you are looking for square numbers, ie `n == x^2` for some `x`

Comment: `if (n/k == k)` does rounding on computing `n/k`.  So `26/5 == 5` will be true - which is incorrect.  You probably need to allow for the rounding in the loop condition too.

Answer (score 1):

An `unsigned` integral type `n` is a power of two if and only if

```
n && !(n & (n - 1))
```

is 1. This works because powers of 2 have only the first bit set to 1 and all other bits set to 0.

In your case your algorithm fails possibly since `int` is too small to represent some of the input cases. Consider using an `unsigned long long` with my method.

Comment: But, int handle 10^9

Comment: @V_head: Not in standard C++, range could be as small as -32767 to +32767, soon to be -32768.

Comment: But this algorithm doesn't solve the question. The question is if `n` is a square number like 9 or 25. n == k²

Comment: @ThomasSablik task is "If n is **power of two** then write "Yes" and "No" in other cases."

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 That's a language issue. Read the code or the title. sqrt has nothing to do with 2^n. OP is trying to implement own sqrt

Comment: @ThomasSablik oh well, only now I realized that probably OP made a mistake when summarizing the task, text says power of two, but code is for detecting square numbers

Answer (score 0):

You can print a range of results and check if they're correct

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

void isSquare(int n) 
{
    if (n == 1) { cout << "Yes"; return; }
    for (int k = 2; k <= (n/k)+1; k++) {
        if (n / k == k) {
            cout << "Yes";
            return;
        }
    }
    cout << "No";
    return;
}

int main() {
    for (int n = 1; n < 40; ++n) {
        std::cout << n << ' ';
        isSquare(n);
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
1 Yes
2 No
3 No
4 Yes
5 Yes
6 No
7 No
8 No
9 Yes
10 Yes
11 Yes
12 No
13 No
14 No
15 No
16 Yes
17 Yes
18 Yes
19 Yes
20 No
21 No
22 No
23 No
24 No
25 Yes
26 Yes
27 Yes
28 Yes
29 Yes
30 No
31 No
32 No
33 No
34 No
35 No
36 Yes
37 Yes
38 Yes
39 Yes
```

As you can see there are many wrong results, e.g. 5 is not a square number. Fix them and you should pass the online judge. You could change

```
if (n / k == k) {
```

to

```
if (n == k * k) {
```

Your approach yields wrong results because of integer division, e.g.

```
5 / 2 == 2
```

You can optimize your algorithm a little with

```
bool isSquare(int n) 
{
    if (n == 1) {
        cout << "Yes";
        return true;
    }
    int k = 2;
    for (; k*k < n; ++k) {}
    if (n == k*k) {
        cout << "Yes";
        return true;
    }
    cout << "No";
    return false;
}
```

You can increment `k` as long as `k*k < n`. After the loop you check if `n == k*k`.

Comment: @V_head You said _"@BoBTFish I tried inputs, corner cases, worst cases, it works."_ How did you try it if there were 13 wrong results in the range from 1 to 40? Create some test cases and find other wrong results. Probably `k <= (n/k)+1;` is to small. You should fix it with `k * k <= n;`.

Comment: Because this problem is not about sqrt, about 2^n. I misunderstood it.